# sort a table while keeping the hierarchy of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table which represents the hierarchy of departments:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| Top Dept. | 2-tier Dept. | 3-tire Dept. | 4-tier Dept. |    name   |  tier |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
|        00 |              |              |              |    abc    |   0   |
|           | 00-01        |              |              |    bcd    |   1   |
|           |              | 00-01-01     |              |    cde    |   2   |
|           |              | 00-01-02     |              |    abc    |   2   |
|           | 00-02        |              |              |    aef    |   1   |
|           |              | 00-02-01     |              |    qwe    |   2   |
|           |              | 00-02-03     |              |    abc    |   2   |
|           |              |              | 00-02-03-01  |    abc    |   3   |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

now I want to sort the rows which are in the same tier by their names while keeping the hierarchy overall, That's what I expect:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| Top Dept. | 2-tier Dept. | 3-tire Dept. | 4-tier Dept. |    name   |  tier |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
|        00 |              |              |              |    abc    |   0   |
|           | 00-02        |              |              |    aef    |   1   |
|           |              | 00-02-03     |              |    abc    |   2   |
|           |              | 00-02-01     |              |    qwe    |   2   |
|           | 00-01        |              |              |    def    |   1   |
|           |              | 00-01-02     |              |    abc    |   2   |
|           |              | 00-01-01     |              |    cde    |   2   |
|           |              |              | 00-02-03-01  |    abc    |   3   |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

the missing data means null, I'm using Oracle DB, can anyone help me?
EDIT: Actually, it's a simple version of [this sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1371/10/0), I've tried to add a new column which concats the values of the first four columns and then order by it and by name, but it did't work.

Comment: please provide SQL statement.

Comment: The missing data in each column can be generated using case statements.  if that's occurring here, you're losing the data needed to sort.  So if you need the output this way add a new column which concats the values of the first four columns as part of the order by and then by name. to retain hierarchy and then sort by name.

Comment: What is the full logic behind your sorting? What if top dept 00's name was zyx, and top dept 01's name was abc; which would be displayed first? Same for the other levels

Comment: @JanisBaiza Now I provide a SQL statement.

Comment: @xQbert I tried what you said, but it didn't work, see my edit.

Comment: @Boneist alphabetical order by column name if they in the same tier.

Comment: Perhaps this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1371/37) but I'm not positive it will work in all cases.  We concat the name instead of department and since hierachy is to be sorted by name... and the recursion builds the hierachy, the sorting should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This appears to be working...  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47a894/1)

All that was really needed from my original comment was to amend name to department in that order in both selects.  This allows the engine to sort by name first, while maintaining the hierarchy.

```
WITH cte(Dept, superiorDept, name, depth, sort)AS (
SELECT 
  Dept,
  superiorDept,
  name,
  0,
  name|| dept
FROM hierarchy h
WHERE superiorDept IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  h2.Dept,
  h2.superiorDept,
  h2.name,
  cte.depth + 1,
  cte.sort || h2.name ||h2.dept
FROM hierarchy h2
INNER JOIN cte ON h2.superiorDept = cte.Dept
)

SELECT 
  CASE WHEN depth = 0 THEN Dept END AS 一级部门,
  CASE WHEN depth = 1 THEN Dept END AS 二级部门,
  CASE WHEN depth = 2 THEN Dept END AS 三级部门,
  CASE WHEN depth = 3 THEN Dept END AS 四级部门,
  name,
  depth,
  sort
FROM cte
ORDER BY sort, name
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the hierarchy goes wrong when the two Dept. in the same tier have the same names using this sql, [for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8689/1/0)

Comment: interesting..  Great question.  I know there's a way, I'll play around with it some more.

Comment: @jfly a deceptively simple task that required more thought than I was putting in.  I think we have it  now though.  Concat name then department in the sort